# How can I set a image from camera as a background in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to set a background with a picture that I'm taking with the app.

thanks

Comment: Can you please make it little bit clear? More explanation and your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you may be it can help you :

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet var imagePreview : UIImageView

@IBAction func AddImageButton(sender : AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.presentModalViewController(imagePicker, animated: true)

}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!) {
    let tempImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    imagePreview.image  = tempImage

    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {

    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

This way you can set Image for your imageView.

Comment: I've did this but I want to use the as a background

Comment: I mean the background of the viewcontroller

Comment: Yes, but I'll add this image to an UIImageView and I want to put this image in the background of the viewcontroller

Comment: I know that but I'd like to use the pic as background.
thank for your help